# ASP.NET Dynamic menu creation with sql data base

Tags: asp.net, sql, dynamic, menu, roles

just wondered what are the steps for a 
role based menu using sitemap and sql server database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial very useful for building a database driven ASP.net menu.

http://aspalliance.com/822